# How to set up redirect url for slack authorization with ngrok

Tags: express, electron, slack, slack-api, ngrok

I have an express app running inside an electron app using http on port 6001 and used ngrok to connect to that port. My question is how can I set the redirect url in Slack's dashboard without knowing the first part of the url i.e `https://xxxx.ngrok.io`. Also, I'm planning to distribute my electron app, what happens when multiple users run the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running your Express App locally and exposing that to Slack using ngrok, then it must be for development only.

Using the ngrok free version, your endpoint will keep on changing every time you restart your desktop.

For development -> Update the Slack webhook with the new ngrok URL everytime it changes.

For production -> Deploy your Express app to a cloud based runtime and then expose that IP address as the URL for the Slack webhook

Comment: Thanks. So ngrok paid plan works well? I have seen local tunnel —subdomain and it might be good for now 

Comment: With ngrok's paid plan you will get custom domains, so no more ephemeral, constantly changing/expiring domains for your secure tunnel. But it will still be a tunnel to your localhost and I would NOT recommend running code for production on your desktop.

Comment: Sounds great. Still unsure about why not get a paid plan and start relaying requests to the localhost express server during production mode.